# Why can I not bind a mount namespace to a file

Tags: linux, namespace, bind-mount, unshare

I observe the following:

As unprivileged user in shell No 1:

```
user@box:~$ sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone
kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone = 1
user@box:~$ unshare --mount --user
nobody@box:~$ echo $$
18655
```

And as root in shell No 2:

```
root@box:~# mkdir -p /tmp/myns
root@box:~# touch /tmp/myns/{user,mnt}
root@box:~# mount --bind /proc/18655/ns/user /tmp/myns/user 
root@box:~# mount --bind /proc/18655/ns/mnt /tmp/myns/mnt
mount: /tmp/myns/mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /proc/18655/ns/mnt, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

The error comes as a surprise: I cannot bind-mount a mount namespace to a file, but I can bind-mount a user-namespace to a file?  Why's that, and how can I make this mount-namespace available to an unprivileged `user`?

**Why I want this**: For testing a program, I want to overlay `~user` with a temporary file system, initially sharing the original contents.  It may be set up by root along the lines of

```
tmp='/tmp/GAtcNNeSfM8b'
mkdir -p "$tmp"
mount -t tmpfs -o size=100m tmpfs "$tmp"
mkdir -p "${tmp}/"{upper,work,lower}
mount --bind -o ro /home/user "${tmp}/lower"

unshare -m
mount -t overlay -o"lowerdir=${tmp}/lower,upperdir=${tmp}/upper,workdir=${tmp}/work" overlay /home/user
touch /tmp/namespace
mount --bind /proc/self/ns/mnt /tmp/namespace
```

but the last line fails.

The intention is that an unprivileged user may `nsenter --mount=/tmp/namespace`, and see the same system as before, except that changes to `/home/user` are not persistent.  Actually, I do not even want to unshare the user namespace.

I am conciously trying to avoid the overhead of LXC, Docker or even VirtualBox.  I think that should be possible with Linux standard tool.

**Update**: I'm running an up-to-date ArchLinux, with

```
$ uname -r
5.0.10-arch1-1-ARCH
```

Comment: Haven't you already get a shell in the newly-created mount namespace? Just write to `/proc/self/uid_map`

Comment: And why all these complex setup, why can't you just `unshare` to get a shell with separate mount and user namespace? Then you can build the overlayfs directly under `/home/user`.

Comment: AFAIK I cannot overlay `/home/user` unless being really privileged (not just fake-privileged as in `unshare -r`).  This might require a kernel patch (lacking sources, but I *think* I've read it is part of Ubuntu's kernels, and controversial due to security concerns — but I'm on ArchLinux anyways).  But if it works on your box, I'd really appreciate to see a working examlpe.

Comment: I did exactly the same as you (including having kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1 which means ubuntu,debian or archlinux, I'm on Debian). Here it's working. 2 possibilities: you have some restriction (selinux & co, already within a container etc.) or it depends on kernel. I'm currently using (debian patched) kernel 5.0.9. Here mounting the mnt nsfs doesn't give an error, and it's really mounted (stat -f -c %T /tmp/myns/mnt  gives nsfs)

Comment: @A.B I'm not inside a container, and I have not tampered with selinux or apparmor (AFAIK they're not even installed,at least not beyond the point of what ArchLinux does by default).  Can anyone reproduce this issue?

Comment: Also see there:  https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/mount_namespaces.7.en.html  . In case there's an interaction with shared filesystems, you should do on the initlal (host) , before anything else, mount --make-private / ; mount --make-private /proc , same for /tmp , and see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

Given that it only affects the mount namespace, I am extremely suspicious that  this is due to one of the [loop prevention checks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473717/what-code-prevents-mount-namespace-loops-in-a-more-complex-case-involving-mount) for mount namespaces.  I do not think it is the exact same case as the link talks about, because `unshare --mount` defaults to setting mount propagation to `private`, i.e. disabling it.

However, to protect against certain race conditions, I think full correctness might require that you mount your mount namespaces inside a mount which has `private` mount propagation.  I also think it might be cleanest (easiest to debug) if you use `unbindable`.  (I think `unbindable` already includes all the effects of `private`).

I.e. mount your mount namespaces inside a directory prepared using:

```
mount --bind /var/local/lib/myns/ /var/local/lib/myns/
mount --make-unbindable /var/local/lib/myns/
```

In general I think this is the safest approach, to avoid ever triggering such a problem.

My race condition is hypothetical.  I would not expect you to be hitting it most of the time.  So I do not know what your actual problem is.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: This was two years ago. & I can't tell whether you're seeing `mount: command not found`, or explaining that you are able to reproduce the original problem on your own Arch Linux system and this suggestion doesn't change the result at all. Neither can another reader. If it was worth pinging me, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: It's not about mount not found, but preparing the directory as you show doesn't fix the mount failing with "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock..."

Comment: I don't think my system reproduces the failure to start with. I'm on Fedora Linux, kernel 5.12.17-300.fc34.x86_64.